# Как подключить скрипт Python в C#?

Tags: c#, python

У меня есть некий скрипт на питоне(со сторонними библиотеками). Я хочу его подключить в готовый  C# проект . 
- Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Для этих целей вам понадобится DynamicLanguageRuntime (или DLR) и IronPython (реализация интерпретатора Python на C#).

Если используете Visual Studio, тут все достаточно просто - используйте NuGet, найдите в нем пакеты DynamicLanguageRuntime и IronPython, установите их. После этого можете запускать скрипты на Python таким образом:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
//Просто указываете python код
engine.Execute("print 'hello, world'");
```

Если хотите запустить скрипт из файла, это можно сделать так:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();

engine.ExecuteFile("ваш_путь_до_скрипта/python_script.py");
```

Подробней и по шагам, можете почитать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/9.3.php)